# Parsing HTML and writing PDF to disk (python)

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup

My goal was to write a script that **downloads all the pdf files from a user entered site**.

- **Problem 1**. the code does not return the anchor tags located inside of the `iframe`. I tried explicitly using the `iframe` tag name and then using `.contents` but the commanded returns an empty list.
- **Question 1**: How to parse the iframe? Why doesn't the `iframe.contents` return its children i.e. the `<a>` tags?
- **Problem 2**: Writing the PDFs to disk appears successful however when I attempt to the files I get the following error,

> "....could not open...because it is either not a supported file type
>   or because the file has been damaged ( for example, it was sent as an
>   email...and wasn't correctly decoded).

- **Question 2**: Anybody encounter this before?

The code is split in two blocks; one for each problem delete the set of quotes around a block to run.

Lastly if anyone can explain why the two urls don't match in the first block of code that would be awesome. Code is commented; contains urls for each question. Thanks!

**PYTHON CODE**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

#initializing counters
slide = 1
count = 0

#ignore SSL cert errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

#get user url and create soup object
url = input("Enter the website name: ")
connect = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
soup = BeautifulSoup(connect, 'html.parser')

######## code block for question 1 revolving around parsing iframes and the issues with the
######## mismatching urls

#url used for code block 1: https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~epapalex/teaching/235_F19/index.html
"""
#trying to retrieve all anchor tags; doesn't print the anchor tags within the iframe
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)
print('\n')

#explictly asking for the iframe tag    
iframe = soup.iframe

#the url printed on this line doesn't match the url printed once I get the src attribute
#navigating to the url listed here is what I use for the second block of code because it
#isn't an iframe
print(iframe)


iframe_src_url = iframe['src']
#this url doesn't match the one shown in the previous print statement and it leaves you dealing
#with another iframe
print(iframe_src_url)
"""


#########code block for question 2 where I enter the url found in the iframe src attribute

#url for block 2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRF408HaDlR6Q9fx6WF6YzeNrZIkXZBqwz_qyN8hz8N4rhIrcpc_GWNMrCODVmucMEUhXIElxcXyDpY/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false
"""
tags = soup('a')

#iterate through tags, retrieve href addresses, navigate to the document, write data to file
for tag in tags:    
    doc_url = tag.get('href')
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(doc_url, context=ctx)
    file = open("Week " + str(slide) + " slides.pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(connect.read())
    file.close()
    print("Finished file: ", slide)

    count = count + 1
    slide = slide + 1

print("Total files downloaded: ", count)"""
```

Comment: Please don't edit questions in ways that invalidated existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~epapalex/teaching/235_F19/index.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('iframe'):
    print(item.get('src'))
```

Output:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRF408HaDlR6Q9fx6WF6YzeNrZIkXZBqwz_qyN8hz8N4rhIrcpc_GWNMrCODVmucMEUhXIElxcXyDpY/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&widget=true&headers=false
```

And Regarding the second question:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRF408HaDlR6Q9fx6WF6YzeNrZIkXZBqwz_qyN8hz8N4rhIrcpc_GWNMrCODVmucMEUhXIElxcXyDpY/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

links = []
for item in soup.findAll('a', {'rel': 'noreferrer'}):
    links.append(item.get('href'))

for item in links:
    r = requests.get(item)
    source = r.headers.get('Location')
    print(f"Saving File {source[56:]}")
    r1 = requests.get(source)
    with open(f"{source[56:]}", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r1.content)
print(f"\nTotal File Downloaded is {len(links)}")
```

Output will save the file to your local disck:

```
Saving File 01-intro-logistics.pdf
Saving File 02-data.pdf
Saving File 03-preprocessing.pdf
Saving File 03-preprocessing.pdf
Saving File 04-frequent-patterns.pdf
Saving File 05a-supervised.pdf
Saving File 05b-supervised.pdf
Saving File 05c-supervised.pdf
Saving File 06a-supervised-advanced.pdf
Saving File 06b-supervised-advanced.pdf
Saving File 07a-unsupervised.pdf
Saving File 07b-unsupervised.pdf
Saving File 07c-advanced-unsupervised.pdf
Saving File 08-graph-mining.pdf
Saving File 09-anomaly-detection.pdf
Saving File 10-time-series.pdf

Total File Downloaded is 16
```

Full Version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html


def Get_Links():
    links = set()
    r = requests.get(
        'https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~epapalex/teaching/235_F19/index.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    source = html.escape(soup.find('iframe').get('src'))
    r = requests.get(source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll('a', {'rel': 'noreferrer'}):
        links.add(item.get('href'))
    return links, len(links)


def Save_Items():
    items, size = Get_Links()
    for item in items:
        r = requests.get(item)
        source = r.headers.get('Location')
        print(f"Saving File {source[56:]}")
        r = requests.get(source)
        with open(f"{source[56:]}", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    print(f"\nTotal File Downloaded is {size}")


Save_Items()
```

Comment: Code for writing pdfs worked perfectly, thanks! Still having a problem parsing the href from the iframe tag. Updated code.

Comment: @StephenStrickland are you just updated your question with the answer which provided to you ? that's against the rules of the community at all ! that's will not be flexible to other viewers to understand the issue.

Comment: running the updated code doesn't result in the pdfs getting downloaded from the url https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~epapalex/teaching/235_F19/index.html which has the links to the pdf files. I highlighted the link in the second picture named 'iframe html'.

Comment: is the only way to interact through the comments after the original post?

Comment: @StephenStrickland well you have changed the question completely. then you asked a new question. that's not how the community operate.

Comment: Apologies. I wanted to post code in the comments but the character limit prevented so I edited the question. Won't do that again. My first question about parsing the iframe remains though; I didn't change that. I also acknowledged your answer on downloading the pdf files wasn't trying to take away from that.

Comment: @StephenStrickland by the way the [link](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~epapalex/teaching/235_F19/slides/02-data.pdf&sa=D&ust=1576645154606000&usg=AFQjCNEyQuXOK2pueiCwx4ZhH5KFNicgoA) which you are talk about is an auto generated link. which keep redirect you the same [source](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~epapalex/teaching/235_F19/slides/02-data.pdf), that's regarding `td <class="s4">` and regarding the first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369259/parsing-html-and-writing-pdf-to-disk-python/59372027#59372027) i already stated on the first point.

Comment: @StephenStrickland I made that for you. https://bpaste.net/show/KB6X6